# Restringir acesso de arquivos apenas a usuários logados

Tags: php

Há como apenas usuários logados visualizarem determinados tipos de arquivos?

Exemplo, se um usuário digitar `www.link.com/arquivo.tpl` se ele estiver logado no sistema visualiza, caso contrário exibe erro.

Comment: Considere usar o HTACCESS para barrar o acesso a esses tipos de arquivo, e disponibilize eles usando o PHP.

Comment: poderia dar uma amostra de como ficaria no PHP a liberação do arquivo?

Comment: Sim vou colocar na resposta desde o bloqueio ate a liberação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro redirecione todas as chamadas de url para um arquivo php fazer a analise do mesmo, no caso vamos redirecionar tudo que contenha .tpl.

> Para isso crie o arquivo ".htaccess" com o seguinte conteudo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.tpl$ checkpermission.php [L]
```

> Crie o arquivo PHP "checkpermission.php" que vai analisar se o arquivo vai ou não vai ser disponibilizado:

```
<?php

//Recupero o caminho absoluto do arquivo
$arquivo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//Sua logica para verificar se o usuario esta logado...
if(isset($_SESSION['logado'])) { // faça o uso da sua verificação!

    //Verifico se o arquivo existe no servidor
    if(file_exists($arquivo))
    {

        //Caso exista disponibiliza o arquivo
        echo file_get_contents($arquivo);

    } else {

        //Caso não exista informo o usuario

        echo '<h1> Erro, o arquivo solicitado não existe!</h1>';

    }

} else {

    //Informo que ele não tem permissão
    echo '<h1>Arquivo disponível apenas para usuários autenticados!</h1>';

}
```

> Coloque os arquivos ".php" e os ".htaccess" na pasta raíz do projeto ou seja na mesma pasta onde fica o index de seu site.

Depois disso é só criar o arquivo .tpl com um conteudo e fazer os testes

**Obs: Para que funcione o mod_rewrite e o .htaccess devem estar habilitados no seu webserver e o mesmo deve ser Apache, no caso do iis deve fazer o mesmo só que com o webconfig. Caso use o XAMPP / WAMPP eles trabalham com base no apache então é só procurar como habilitar o mod_rewrite neles, essa opção vem por padrão habilitada mas caso não funcione considere fazer essa verificação.**

Comment: Irei fazer os testes agora, volto depois com o feedback por enquanto obrigado @Hiago Souza

Comment: Disponha, caso te ajude considere marcar a resposta como correta. E efetuar um cadastro no site para colaborar ;)

Comment: Com certeza amigo, uma obs. preciso informar o caminho dos arquivos `.tpl` no `.htaccess` ou não há necessidade?

Comment: Não a expressão regular do htaccess "\.tpl$ " vai pegar qualquer coisa que termine com .tpl

Comment: As únicas modificações que acho que você deva fazer é as mensagens de retorno por exemplo a mensagem para autenticar, a que o arquivo não existe... e a que tenho certeza que você deve modificar é a condição que verifica se o usuário esta logado (primeiro IF).

Comment: Tendi, @HiagoSouza me deparei com um probleminha, se eu acessar o arquivo `../arquivo.tpl?_=89898989` não encontra